# How to prevent google sheets from updating display values when converting Microsoft Excel file to google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm trying to convert an Excel file to a google spreadsheet. This is working fine. I'm using the following code:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&convert=true", {

 method: "POST",
 contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
 payload: file.getBlob().getBytes(),
 headers: {
   "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  }

);
```

The problem is that all the values of the google spreadsheet convert to '#REF!'. This is because all the formulas in the Microsoft Excel sheet refer to external sheets and when the google spreadsheet tries to run the formulas again, it can't find these values so it returns '#REF!'. My question is whether it's possible to get the display values of the Microsoft Excel sheet. I can see them when I open the Excel sheet in preview mode in Google Drive, but I want to access them with code. I receive these Excel files almost daily by email so I would like to have a solution where I don't have to do any manual action. Thanks for any input.

Edit:

To be more clear, the formulas in the Excel sheet are in the following form:

```
=IF('file:///fileName.xlsx'#$'Input'.D29="","",'file:///fileName.xlsx'#$'Input'.D29)
```

Comment: Strange. I just tried out your code on an excel 2007 file and references to other sheets are converted correctly.

Comment: @SpiderPig , to be more clear, the formulas in the Excel sheet are in this form `=IF('file:///fileName.xlsx'#$'Input'.D29="","",'file:///fileName.xlsx'#$'Input'.D29)`. Google sheets converts it to '#REF!', instead of just leaving the display value.